# Mac pro 2,1 boots up but won't restart?

Tags: mac, boot, memory, reboot, mac-pro

I am very confused with this problem. So I just recently purchased a 8 core 3.0ghz Mac Pro 2,1 and I upgraded the memory with 16gbs of hynix ram, and everything worked great the computer was reading all 16gbs of memory and I thought all was well but when I tried to restart the computer it just shuts off and the screen goes black and there are no start up chimes or anything. So I have to hold the power button and shut it off all the way and then reboot it and everything works fine again until I try to restart it again? Any help would be appreciated. I am running OSX Lion! P.S there are no led lights that are illuminated on the memory boards!

Answer (score 0):

Try reseting the **NVRAM**. To do this, just hold **Option-Command-P-R** after the chime sound.

If this doesn't solve the issue, boot using the verbose mode (just hold Command-V after the chime sound) and let's see why the restart process does not restart...

Here you have all the boot commands: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1533